# Count array counts 1 too many

Tags: php, arrays, count

Does anyone know how to get arround the annoying problem that when counting how many values there is inside an array if the value is 0 it says 1 becuase it counts the name or something. So like this:

```
0 : 1
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
4 : 4
5 : 5
6 : 6
7 : 7
8 : 8
```

Comment: Show us how you create an array and what function you're using to count its values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fully answer the question, I'd need the code for this.

My sneaking suspicion is that whatever you are `count()`ing isn't an empty array the first time, but something else. An initialized, non-null, non-array and non-[`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php)-object variable has a `count()` of 1.

See [count's documentation](http://php.net/count) for more info.

Comment: Haha, thank-you, just placed this code there and it works now ;)

if (!is_array($friends2)) {
$friends2 = array();
}